# ReactJS bind method to class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Im doing ReactJS course in Codeacademny and they confused me.

(EDIT - full code) Photo of the code :

[image: Code]

and there's no constructor or anywhere call to any bind method for the `scream` class method.

However in further exercises they tell you can't do that.

I probably miss something.

Comment: Really depends on how the function is defined and what it does.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `this.scream` is an arrow function. Arrow function does not require binding. It points to the right context by default.

```
scream = () => { ... }
```

Comment: That's only part of the story. The arrow function is also defined as a class property, which means it is actually evaluated and set inside the constructor, where `this` points to the instance.

Answer (score 1):

> and there's no constructor or anywhere call to any bind method for the scream class method.

You only have to bind `this` to the component instance when the method actually uses `this` internally.

That's not the case in your example, so there is no need to bind it. No matter how the method is executed, it will always produce the same output.

Here is an example without React to demonstrate the difference:

```js
var obj = {
  value: 42,
  method1() { // doesn't use `this`
    console.log("yey!");
  },
  method2() { // uses `this`
    console.log(this.value);
  },
};

obj.method1(); // works
obj.method2(); // works

var m1 = obj.method1;
var m2 = obj.method2;

m1(); // works
m2(); // BROKEN!

var m2bound = obj.method2.bind(obj);
m2bound(); // works
```

Comment: I just began with React so I haven't seen yet how class component instance looks like.

Comment: That has nothing to do with React. When you are calling `new SomeClass()` in JavaScript, you are creating a new *instance* of the class (an object). Methods are typically called on the instance and a method can refer to the instance via `this`. You asked why the method is not bound (to the component instance), so that's what I answered.

Comment: But there no call for `new Someclass()` in the code I posted. It's more similar to this `obj.method1();`

Comment: You are passing the class to React at some point. React instantiates the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
scream = () => { ... }

render() {
    return <button onClick={()=>this.scream()}>AAAAAH!</button>;
  }
```

Comment: in onClick method also we need to use arrow function

Comment: *"in onClick method also we need to use arrow function"* No. Since `this.scream` is an arrow function, `() => this.scream()` and `this.scream` are identical.

Answer (score 0):

ou have to be careful about the meaning of this in JSX callbacks. In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to bind this.handleClick and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined when the function is actually called.

This is not React-specific behavior; it is a part of how functions work in JavaScript. Generally, if you refer to a method without () after it, such as 
`onClick={this.handleClick}`, you should bind that method.

When you define a component using an ES6 class, a common pattern is for an event handler to be a method on the class. For example, this Toggle component renders a button that lets the user toggle between “ON” and “OFF” states:

````js
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      isToggleOn: !state.isToggleOn
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Toggle />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);```
````

Comment: Yeah thanks, I read about that. That's why what I saw in Codeacademy didn't fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an arrow function (no need to bind in constructor).

```
 scream = () => { console.log('Here') }

 render() {
    return <button onClick={this.scream}>AAAAAH!</button>;
  }
```

Or you can call this function inline by.

```
 render() {
        return <button onClick={() => console.log('Here')}>AAAAAH!</button>;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use arrow functions for event handling to bind the function to the object. Other solution is to auto bind each function in the constructor like :

```
class Test{
   constructor(){
       Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Test.prototype).forEach(
                      method => this[method] = this[method].bind(this));
}
```

Read about @AutoBind decorator for more details.

Comment: The arrow one was offered here several times (although not responding to my question about Codeacademy's code). The autobind however, really makes me think why javascript designers couldn't just to that for us implicitly.